# Change <Jsp:include page:> with button on click

Tags: jsp

i would like to change  `<:jsp include page:"includes.jsp">` with input button onclick. So for example, i have a jsp page "index.jsp" which have `<jsp include page:"includes.jsp">` . In another jsp page, "themes.jsp". is it possible for me to edit the 
`<jsp include page:"includes.jsp">` to something else like 
`<jsp include page:"includes_blue.jsp">` ?

Comment: Can you please explain the question more clearly?You want to forward the variables to another jsp on button click??

Comment: yes that's right. i want to change the include page by button click from another jsp

Comment: can i know why you want to edit the include tag?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to problem seems to be wrong.

You cannot edit `JSP` tags on click event. On click event happens on browser and no `JSP` tags but only `HTML` tags are sent to browser.
On browser side you have `javascript`. You should consider using `javascript` for your solution.

Another way would be to pass the desired theme to server and include appropriate jsp based on the theme. Note This will reload the page.

Comment: yes i have thought of that as well. but is it possible to have a javascript to edit the content for <jsp include page> ?